# document.getElementById("b1").checked not working in Mozila and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The below code work on Internet explore perfectly but not on Mozilla FireFox or Chrome

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sp</title>
<script>
function hh()
{
if(document.getElementById("b1").checked)
{
var p=150
var q=document.getElementById("q1").value
var t=p*q
alert(t)
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
<input size="1" name="q1" value="1"> Quantity<br>
<br>
<input onclick="hh()" name="p1" value="Purchase" type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

if i use code without `getElementById` its works properly, but when I add it, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have no element with id `b1` so the function is returning null, and will throw a cannot read property error

```
<input name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
```

should have an id attribute

```
<input id="b1" name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
```

This also applies to your `q1` input as well, you do not have an id on it

Also which version of IE is this working for you? As you should be getting a similar error in your console as chrome and firefox

Comment: `As you should be getting a similar error`. Elements have `name` attributes and IE uses them instead of ids in this case. That's why it works.

Comment: Yea I thought as much, which is why i asked the version they were using, since 9+ does not seem to have that behavior (at least not in the tests I ran changing the document mode emulation in my IE11)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because u r not using **id** in html tags.

Just add id in ur html tags and update ur html as :

```
<input id="b1" name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
<input size="1" name="q1" value="1" id="q1"> Quantity<br>
```

instead :

```
<input name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
<input size="1" name="q1" value="1"> Quantity<br>
```

`document.getElementById` **works on id not name.**

Comment: U r not getting error in IE because IE is using ur name attribute and works perfectly in IE but this is not the case in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` works for `id` not for `name`

use

```
<input id="b1" name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
```

or use

```
document.getElementsByName("b1")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

pass an Id to document.getElementById() not Name
so

```
    <input name="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
```

to

```
    <input name="b1" id="b1" type="checkbox">Add To cart<br>
```

and 
use

```
    <input onclick="javascript:hh();" name="p1" value="Purchase" type="submit">
```

instead of

```
    <input onclick="hh()" name="p1" value="Purchase" type="submit">
```